# Having a problem with Kattis with what I'm assuming is a extreme case

Tags: java

I could use some help with the Kattis exercise [Neigborhood Watch](https://open.kattis.com/problems/neighborhoodwatch). I fail on the 11th test because of a wrong answer, and I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

Jennifer was nominated to be neighborhood watch captain and is now in charge of managing the watch for her street.

Jennifer’s street consists of houses on only one side of the road. She has a plan of which houses will be a neighborhood watch house and wants to know how safe the plan is. A walk from one house to another house (not necessarily distinct) is considered safe if there is at least one house along the walk that is a neighborhood watch house. The safety rating of a plan is the number of walks that are safe on the street. Since a walk is either safe or not safe, when traveling in either direction, it is not counted twice in the safety rating.

Tell Jennifer the safety rating of her plan.
Input

The first line of input contains two integers N
 (1≤N≤200000), which is the number of houses on the street, and K (0≤K≤N), which is the number of neighborhood watch houses in Jennifer’s plan. The houses are numbered 1,…,N.

The next K lines describe the neighborhood watch houses. Each of these lines contains a single integer H (1≤H≤N), which is the house number of a neighborhood watch house. The house numbers are given in strictly increasing order.

Output

Display the safety rating of her system(display the number of safe walk possible).

```
public class NeighborhoodWatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String first[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(first[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(first[1]);
        int ks[] = new int[k];
        int x=0;
        int y=k;
        while (y>0) {
            ks[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            x++;
            y--;
        }
        Arrays.sort(ks);
        long count = 0;
        //This loop runs through the safe houses(if they exist).
        //It takes the remaining number of houses from the sad house onwards and multiplies it with the number of houses since the previous safe house. Which should be correct. And with a special case for the first one where you multiply by the number of houses to the first house on the street.
        if (k>0) {
            count = (n-ks[0]+1)*ks[0];
            for(int i=1;i<k;i++) {
                count += (n-ks[i]+1)*(ks[i]-ks[i-1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Example: 
Input:

5 2

1

4

Expected output:

11

I'm putting it into a black box for testing, and I passed the first 10, but got a wrong answer on the 11th one. So I'm assuming it is some case I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

*Note you don't need to sort the houses because they are already given to you in increasing order*

I solved this in python and the method I used was to calculate for each house, the first index of a safe house close to it. I treat walking to this initial safe house as a walk of length 1. Then I add up the number of houses after that safe house and add that to my count.

For example, given N = 5, and k = [3,4,5]. For each house:

1. `(1 -> 3 = 1)` + `(5 - 3)` = `3`
2. `(2 -> 3 = 1)` + `(5 - 3)` = `3`
3. `(3 -> 3 = 1)` + `(5 - 3)` = `3`
4. `(4 -> 4 = 1)` + `(5 - 4)` = `2`
5. `(5 -> 5 = 1)` + `(5 - 5)` = `1`

Gives a total of 12